# MQTT to check if Message is delivered and other user Online/Offline Status

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, mqtt, xcode9

I am developing an iOS chat messaging App using MQTT, In this App i have to show other user online/offline status and message Send & Deliver Status. 
Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Online/offline status can be retrieved in this kind of method.
[Checking Active MQTT Client Connections](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/checking-active-mqtt-client-connections/).
This guy uses sensors, but working principle is the same.

Message sent status can be obtained if you're using QOS1 or QOS2, so it guarantees delivery to server.

Message delivered can be done with publishing to the recipient's topic. You are sure that message is delivered, if another client published some sort of acknowledgment.